# How do I categorize file contents based on regex into different groups?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a flat file that contains a list of packages that are existing in the system. I want to find out if the package is

1. a batch component (conventionally, names begin with `batch`),
2. a service (names end with `serv`)
3. a messaging daemon (names end with `d`)
4. a web component (names end with `web`)
5. and those that don't fall into any category (meaning not named per convention)

I have written this bash script for the same:

```
grep serv$ pack_list.txt > serv_list.txt
grep d$ pack_list.txt > daemon_list.txt
grep ^batch pack_list.txt > batch_list.txt
grep web$ pack_list.txt > web_list.txt
grep -v serv$ pack_list.txt | grep -v d$ | grep -v ^batch | grep -v web$ > uncat_list.txt
```

While it satisfies my current requirement and does not take much time, I cannot help but wonder if some other language would be a better choice for these kind of operations.

---EDIT--

Example input would be:

```
fileserv
batch_file_processor
userweb
processord
```

Each would go into a different file.

To clarify what I am looking for: I am looking for some language where this processing would have better syntactic support than:

1. A command like `grep` for each regex.
2. A series of `if` conditions like Python or Perl would do.

Something along the lines of:

```
switch line.match($1):
    case (pattern1):
          ...
    case (pattern2):
          ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where would `batch_test.serv` go? 1st or second group? or both?

Comment: Real data and expected output, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single Awk process can do this much better, for each line  matching against your patterns and redirecting output appropriately:

```
awk '{
  if ($0 ~ /serv$/) { print > "serv_list.txt" }
  else if ($0 ~ /d$) { print > "daemon_list.txt" }
  // ... and so on
  else { print > "uncat_list.txt" }
}' pack_list.txt
```